# How to solve $rem(7^{14},18)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am trying to solve $rem(7^{14},18)$

So here I started with $(7^7)^2$.

But I don't know how to go on.

I am so sorry there was a typo, it should be 18 instead of 8.My bad.

Comment: Does $rem(7^{14},8)$ mean the remainder when you divide $7^{14}$ by $8$?

Comment: Start with $(7^2)^7$. Or, if you're familiar with modular arithmetic, just note that $7 \equiv -1 \mod 8$

Comment: You can use the binomial theorem and notice that $7^{14}=(8-1)^{14})$. All of the terms have an $8$ in them except $8^0(-1^{14})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When considering this case you can observe the multiplicity applies to the value congruent to in mod8 as well. 
As such:
$$7\equiv 7 mod8 $$
Then multiplying by 7 yields:
$$ 49 \equiv 1 mod8 $$
This multiplicity  can be continued through to show all odd powers of 7 will be 7mod8 and all even powers will be 1mod8. As such 
$$ rem ( 7^{14},8) =1 $$

Continuing on, for your edited case. 
Observe that:
$$7^{14}=(7^7)^2=(7^3*7^4)^2$$
$$7^4\equiv 7 mod 18 $$
$$7^3\equiv 1 mod 18 $$
$$\Longrightarrow 7^7\equiv 7*1 mod 18  $$
$$\Longrightarrow (7^7)^2\equiv (7*1)^2 mod 18  $$
$$\Longrightarrow 7^{14} \equiv 49 mod 18 \equiv 13 mod 8 $$
$$\therefore rem(7^{14},18)=13 $$

Comment: could you please show me how it's done by change 8 to 18? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: 7^2 =49 => 13 = -5 mod 18;7^3 = -35 = 1 mod 18.  So 7^3, 7^6, 7^9, 7^12 = 1 mod 18 so 7^14 = 7^2 = 13 mod 18.  So the remainder is 13.

Comment: @display888 sure just give me a moment. Stepping into my lab. Ill set up and solve for you in a second.

Comment: @JordanButler that's prefect! I am all ears sir.

Comment: @DISPLAY888 Sorry about the delay, the solution has been edited for your new problem.

Answer (score 1):

$(1+6k)^3=1+3(6k)+3(6k)^2+(6k)^3\equiv1\pmod{18}$

$k=1\implies7^3=343\equiv1\pmod{18}$

$7^{14}=7^2(7^3)^4\equiv7^2\cdot1^4\pmod{18}\equiv13$